# IF multiple files exist BAT file

Tags: file, if-statement, batch-file

I need to do a .BAT file to check if two files exists.

- If both files exist, it should run `program1`
- if only FileA exists, run `ProgramA`
- if only FileB exists, run `ProgramB`
- if none exist, exit.

Please help

What I got so far is this (it is not working, always goes to option B):

```
if exist "c:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_A.txt" (
    if exist "c:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_B.txt" (
        goto :Exist2
    ) else goto :ExistA
) else goto :ExistB
goto end

:Exist2
echo run Program1 
goto end

:ExistA
echo run ProgramA
goto end

:ExistB
echo run ProgramB
goto end


:End
echo  ------------ FIN ---------------
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: runs fine for me. Do you have some non-English characters in your folder/file names?

Comment: @Stephan, just looking at that code suggests to me that if FileA doesn't exist, it will `goto :ExistB`, although no code has determined at that time whether FileB exists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the environment variable `FilesExist` as a bit mask.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FilesExist=0"
if exist "C:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_A.txt" set "FilesExist=1"
if exist "C:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_B.txt" set /A "FilesExist|=2"
goto Exist%FilesExist%

:Exist3
echo run Program1
goto End

:Exist2
echo run ProgramB
goto End

:Exist1
echo run ProgramA

:End
:Exist0
echo  ------------ FIN ---------------
endlocal
```

The environment variable `FilesExist` is initialized with value `0` and keeps this value on both files not existing.

The variable `FilesExist` is redefined with value `1` if the first file exists.

The current value `0` or `1` of the variable `FilesExist` is with an arithmetic expression bitwise OR combined with value `2` on second file exists. The result is `2` on just second file exists and `3` on both files exist.

The **GOTO** command uses the resulting value of the variable `FilesExist` for continuation of the batch file processing below the right label depending on the existence of the two files.

Another solution is the combination of the bit mask with a pseudo array if the goal is just running one of three different programs as suggested by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Program1=ProgramA"
set "Program2=ProgramB"
set "Program3=Program1"
set "FilesExist="
if exist "C:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_A.txt" set "FilesExist=1"
if exist "C:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_B.txt" set /A "FilesExist|=2"
if not defined FilesExist goto End
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo run "!Program%FilesExist%!"
endlocal
:End
echo  ------------ FIN ---------------
endlocal
```

The value `0` is used on second **IF** condition by command **SET** on first file not existing in which case the variable `FilesExist` does also not exist on evaluation of the arithmetic expression with the bitwise OR. That is guaranteed according to usage help of command **SET** output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window.

Comment: I like this method! **`:)`** However, I would use an array to simplify the "execution" code:  `set "prog[1]=ProgramA" & set "prog[2]=ProgramB" & set "prog[3]=Program1"` so finally: `echo run !prog[%FilesExist%]!`

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you have been given an overall better solution in the comments, I thought I'd offer this simple restructured example:

```bash
If Exist "C:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_A.txt" GoTo ExistA
If Not Exist "C:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_B.txt" GoTo End

Echo run ProgramB
GoTo End

:ExistA
If Exist "C:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_B.txt" GoTo Exist2
Echo run ProgramA
GoTo End

:Exist2
Echo run Program1

:End
Echo  ------------ FIN ---------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

```
set "program="
If Exist "C:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_A.txt" (
   set "program=ProgramA"
   If Exist "C:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_B.txt" (
      set "program=program1"
   )
) else If Exist "C:\temp\test333\Enviar\Archivo_a_Enviar_B.txt" (
   set "program=ProgramB"
)

echo run %program%
```